# Should I use Angular UI Bootstrap or plain Bootstrap 3?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

At time of writing Angular UI Bootstrap is based on Twitter Bootstrap 2 while the latest version is Bootstrap 3. If I were to write an application in Angular.js TODAY, what UI framework should I use? Angular UI or just plain Bootstrap?

What pros and cons are there? Both in the long and short term.

Comment: For the life of me; I don't understand why these sorts of questions get closed. I think the "closed as primarily opinion-based" gets completely overused as close reason, bordering abuse. There is a huge difference between a "which is better?" question and a user (like this question) that asks to enumerate the pro and cons. The usefulness of these questions is greatly underestimated by closing them off (and others alike). I mean; 6000+ views? Apparently people want to know the answer to this question.

Comment: This is a very good and very important question!

Comment: Great question, I don't get why it has been closed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a bootstrap 3 branch going on in angular UI bootstrap, and almost everything has been migrated to bootstrap 3 in this branch. You can build this branch by yourself, and it's a matter of days or weeks before an official release that supports bootstrap 3 is made. You should go with it.

Comment: I had the same dilemma and decided to go with bootstrap3 for the same reason JB mentions. You have to build it yourself, but that is pretty straightforward, the top FAQ points you in the right direction: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 5):

As you can see on this link in the repo of `Angular UI` ([Bootstrap3 support](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#bootstrap3-support)), support for `Bootstrap3` is almost ready.

You are talking about long-term, so I am assuming your application isn't going to production in the next month, so I would go with `Bootstrap3` and the `bootstrap3` branch of `AngularUI`. But if you want something stable right now, I thing you should go with `Bootstrap 2.3` and be prepared to update your code in the next months.

Comment: I made an application for calculation of income tax in India. I needed to use popovers and dropdowns and collapsible divs in the application. I tried to do it in Angular UI. It works fine in plunker and on the site. But the same code will not fire on my system. I tried every way to get it working with no result. Finally I used data-toggle etc in bootstrap 3.0 and got it working easily.